# Azure IP Translation

Tags: azure, nat, subnet

We are moving our Webserver to Azure, it is hosting about 5 sites today, each listening on a private IP. We are using NAT to translate incomming request to the correct private IP at the edge router. Like this:

Internet public IPs --> Router (Translate to private IP) --> Server.

I have setup a VM on Azure with 5 NICs, each with a private IP-adress.
How can I translate from 5 different incomming public IPs to my 5 private? (One Azure VM instance can only have one public IP)

Another way to put it, how do I use NAT 1-to-1 on Azure to my subnet?

Comment: Did you assign the public IP to the private one when configuring them as per this guide https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell ?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using Virtual Hosts instead of dedicated IP's?

Answer (score 2):

As Drifter104’s link, Azure will support that any NIC could have one or more static or dynamic public and private IP addresses assigned to it. I think this new feature maybe achieve your scenario.

Notes: This feature is currently in preview release and may not have the same level of availability and reliability as features that are in general availability release.

You could assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines using the Azure Portal. More information please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal).

Comment: Now, Azure supports multiple IPs on one NIC, you could refer this [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal).